# MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst size limitation

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

anyone know if the 
MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst

SizeCount when do marsheling has size limitation. 
i see that if the Size large then 100000 the marsheling  function calling is not working and when i put 10000 the function is working.

anybody know why ?

Comment: The limit is 64KB.  No idea why, the marshaller code is rough.

Comment: Heh. The idea of a c function taking a  pass-by-value array of hundreds of thousands of elements is pretty ludicrous; one would think the number of assembly calls to push that much data into the stack would be amazing...although of suppose repsb/stosb could be used.

Answer (score 1):

As Hans Passant says, there is a 64K limit and I don't know why.
You can always try another approach with Marshal.AllocHGlobal and Marshal.PtrToStructure/Marshal.StructureToPtr. However, I don't know if you can handle it that way; if not, you must write data piece by piece then pass the pointer to the allocated block to the API function.